# ImportError: No module named pynput

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pynput

so I installed pynput (pip install pynput) but it is still giving me an error that I didn't install it. Is there a reason for this? Thanks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pynput import mouse
ImportError: No module named pynput
```

Comment: Did you install it into the Python environment you're using in VSCode?

Comment: Perhaps you installed the module for python 2 and your script is using python 3?

Comment: I don't know, how would I do it. All I ran was: pip install pynput

Comment: I am using python 3.

Comment: If `pip3 install pynput` fails because pip3 doesn't exist, then the suggestion in my previous comment isn't the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your pip install was pointing to a different python version than the one thats running that script

you can usually solve this by doing `python -m pip install <package>`  (which will make sure to install it for the python version that `python` points to)

if you are just using system python try using `python3 -m pip install XXX` as pip by itself is probably referencing python2

if you are using a virtualenv in vscode you will need to activate that version with `<venv_path>/bin/activate` then you can run `python -m pip install XXXX`

Comment: ```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 163, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, _Error)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(mod_name)  # Do not catch exceptions initializing package
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from typing import List, Optional
ImportError: No module named typing
```

Comment: `python` must be pointing to python2 ... try my other suggestion`python3` (but at a guess if you are in vscode it is using a virtualenv, which you need to activate before running that command)

Comment: Its working now! Thank you so much. I had to run python3 test.py

Comment: @FishyMine: Another way to do a similar thing is to use `pip3 install <package>` instead of `python3 -m pip install <package>`.

Comment: @SamMatzko in my experience especially for newer developers using `python -m pip`  instead helps them avoid this problem much better

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Just wondering: how is it different, other than syntax?

Comment: it just helps ensure that you are usiing the python you expect :P

Comment: `python -m pip` will use the version of Python that `python` currently refers to; `pip` will use whichever version `pip` currently refers to. These can differ due to a misconfigured PATH, and possibly other reasons I'm not thinking of right now. `python3` and `pip3` will get *some* 3.x installation even if `python` and `pip` respectively would use a 2.x installation, but there are still other issues. We really need some kind of master post on managing multiple Python installations (and venvs).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel put it much better than I did

Comment: Another issue is that on Windows, `pip` can't upgrade itself, due to (as I understand it) how Windows implements protection against self-modifying executables. `python -m pip` will work because it's now `python.exe` that's running, rather than the `pip.exe` wrapper executable.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Ah, that makes sense.